# Nodemon keeps logging middleware stuff even when no one is doing requests

Tags: node.js, express, package.json

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Logging...")
  next();
})
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Authenticated...")
  next();
})


const courses = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'JavaScript',
    description: 'JavaScript is a high-level, dynamic, untyped, and interpreted programming language.'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Node.js',
    description: 'Node.js is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome\'s V8 JavaScript engine.'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Express',
    description: 'Express is a minimal and flexible Node.js web application framework.'
  }
];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
})

//every req,res callback it's a middleware
app.get('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
   res.send(courses);
})

app.get('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
  const course = courses.find(course => course.id == req.params.id)
  if(!course) {
    res.status(404).send('Course not found');
  }
  else {
    res.send(course);
  }
})

app.post('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
   //for this to work we need to enabling parsing the body of the request
   const schema = Joi.object({
     name: Joi.string().required(),
     description: Joi.string().required()
   });
   const result = schema.validate(req.body);

   if(result.error) {
      res.status(400).send(result.error);
      return
   }
   else {
  const course = {
     id: courses.length + 1,
     name: req.body.name,
     description: req.body.description
  }
  courses.push(course);
  //this sends the course object back to the client in the body of the response
  //(which is the standard way to do this)
  res.send(course);
}})

app.put('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
   const course = courses.find(course => course.id == req.params.id)
   if(!course) {
     res.status(404).send('Course not found');
   }
   else if (!req.body.name && !req.body.description) {
      res.status(404).send('Wrong property bitch')
   }
   else {
     course.name = req.body.name ?? course.name;
     course.description = req.body.description ?? course.description;
     res.send(course);
   }
})

app.delete('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
   const course = courses.find(course => course.id == req.params.id)
   if(!course) {
     res.status(404).send('Course not found');
   }
   else {
     courses.splice(courses.indexOf(course), 1);
     res.send('Course deleted');
   }
})


app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
})
```

It keeps logging this over and over

Logging...
Authenticated...
Logging...
Authenticated...
Logging...
Authenticated...
Logging...
Authenticated...
Logging...
Authenticated...
Logging...
Authenticated...
Logging...
Authenticated...
Logging...
Authenticated...
Logging...

This is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodefundamentals",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "joi": "^17.4.2"
  }
}
```

package.json and the app.js file as the only 2 I have. How can I solve this?

I feel like I'm missing something, but I followed the tutorial line by line and I've been getting this recursive logs for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

please replace ?? with ||.

instead of else if use if return i have made a fixed repl here

the index code

```
    const Joi = require('joi');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Logging...")
  next();
})
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Authenticated...")
  next();
})


const courses = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'JavaScript',
    description: 'JavaScript is a high-level, dynamic, untyped, and interpreted programming language.'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Node.js',
    description: 'Node.js is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome\'s V8 JavaScript engine.'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Express',
    description: 'Express is a minimal and flexible Node.js web application framework.'
  }
];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
})

//every req,res callback it's a middleware
app.get('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
   res.send(courses);
})

app.get('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
  const course = courses.find(course => course.id == req.params.id)
  if(!course) {
    res.status(404).send('Course not found');
  }
  else {
    res.send(course);
  }
})

app.post('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
   //for this to work we need to enabling parsing the body of the request
   const schema = Joi.object({
     name: Joi.string().required(),
     description: Joi.string().required()
   });
   const result = schema.validate(req.body);

   if(result.error) {
      res.status(400).send(result.error);
      return
   }
   else {
  const course = {
     id: courses.length + 1,
     name: req.body.name,
     description: req.body.description
  }
  courses.push(course);
  //this sends the course object back to the client in the body of the response
  //(which is the standard way to do this)
  res.send(course);
}})

app.put('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
   const course = courses.find(course => course.id == req.params.id)
   if(!course) return res.status(404).send('Course not found');
   
   if (!req.body.name && !req.body.description )return res.status(404).send('Wrong property bitch')
   

     course.name = req.body.name || course.name;
     course.description = req.body.description || course.description;
     res.send(course);

})

app.delete('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
   const course = courses.find(course => course.id == req.params.id)
   if(!course) return res.status(404).send('Course not found');
   
     courses.splice(courses.indexOf(course), 1);
     res.send('Course deleted');
   
})


app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it doesn't fix the error in my machine. I guess it's not the index file.

Comment: ya and if you want a through error check put it in github